# How much should I be watering my peach, pear and plum trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, watering

I have one tree of each of the following: peach, plum and pear.

They have been in the ground for less than a year.

How many (gallons per week) should I be watering each tree?

I'm in coastal southern California, so I don't get a whole lot of rain.

Answer (score 4):

I live quite close to where you are, so pretty much the same climate. I have a peach and a plum a little older than yours and I typically water them twice a week (once/week in late fall/"winter" months) till the surrounding ground is soaked upto about, 6" deep at the very least.

I'm hesitant to give a gallons/week number, as I don't think it makes much sense. In general, the advice for trees is to water deep, so as to encourage the roots to grow downwards and water wide, so that the roots also grow outwards. If you do it narrow and shallow, you'll have a tree with roots that are close to the surface and the tree and will be easily uprooted in a strong wind (not that we have many of